# Built in function to compare strings in C++?

Tags: c++, function, built-in

I need some built-in function to compare `string`s. For C-style strings I have

```
strcmp();
```

But I need some function to deal with the `string` class.

```
string name1;
string name2;
```

Comment: http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: -1. If "==" maybe hard to find, just search for title should have revealed at least something - http://www.bing.com/search?q=function+to+compare+string+in+c%2B%2B%3F gives plenty of `string::compare` links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use [`std::string::compare()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) which provides the same functionality as `strcmp()`.

```
std::string name1 = "John";
std::string name2 = "Micheal";

int result = name1.compare(name2);
```

Would roughly be the same as:

```
const char* name1 = "John";
const char* name2 = "Micheal";

int result = std::strcmp(name1, name2);
```

Answer (score 10):

You're looking for [the equality operator, **`operator==()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp), which is defined for [`std::basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
if (name1 == name2)
```

Other comparison operators are also available, namely `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=`.

Comment: you may add about std::string::compare too?

Comment: I *could* add about [`std::basic_string::compare()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare), which is closer in syntax to the C function, but I choose not to since the operators make for much more readable code.

Comment: @Koushik: Unfortunately, the OP does not agree!